# Convert Pandas Dataframe from Row based to Columnar

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
Date       FieldA  ValueA ValueB
09-02-2016 TypeA   3       5
09-02-2016 TypeB   6       7
```

I want the dataframe to look like below:

```
Date       TypeA_ValueA   TypeA_ValueB  TypeB_ValueA TypeB_ValueB
09-02-2016  3             5             6            7
```

I tired the df.pivot in pandas where I can provide single Value column. It doesnt take more than one. When I provide more than one i get below exception. [pandas_pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Date', 'FieldA']).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)

df1.reset_index()
```

[image]

---

#### Setup Reference

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """Date       FieldA  ValueA ValueB
09-02-2016 TypeA   3       5
09-02-2016 TypeB   6       7"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)

df
```

[image]

Comment: getting error : TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: now getting new error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Answer (score 0):

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
        Date FieldA  ValueA  ValueB
0 2016-09-02  TypeA       3       5
1 2016-09-02  TypeB       6       7
2 2016-09-03  TypeA       4       8
3 2016-09-03  TypeB       3       9

In [37]: v_cols = df.columns.difference(['FieldA', 'Date'])

In [38]: def func(x):
     ...:     d = {'_'.join([t, c]): x[x['FieldA'] == t][c].iloc[0] for t in x.FieldA for c in v_cols}
     ...:     for k, v in d.iteritems():
     ...:         x[k] = v
     ...:     return x
     ...: 

In [39]: newdf = df.groupby('Date').apply(func)

In [40]: newdf.drop(v_cols.tolist() + ['FieldA'], axis=1).drop_duplicates()
Out[340]: 
        Date  TypeA_ValueA  TypeA_ValueB  TypeB_ValueA  TypeB_ValueB
0 2016-09-02             3             5             6             7
2 2016-09-03             4             8             3             9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.pivot_table`.

```
In [1]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date', columns='FieldA', values=['ValueA', 'ValueB'])
Out[1]: 
           ValueA       ValueB      
FieldA      TypeA TypeB  TypeA TypeB
Date                                
09-02-2016      3     6      5     7
```

As a result, you'll get a DataFrame with MultiIndex. If you want to flatten it and have `_` as separator in the column name, you can just do:

```
In [1]: df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date', columns='FieldA', values=['ValueA', 'ValueB'])

In [2]: df.columns = [ '{}_{}'.format(cat, val) for val, cat in df.columns ]

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
            TypeA_ValueA  TypeB_ValueA  TypeA_ValueB  TypeB_ValueB
Date                                                              
09-02-2016             3             6             5             7
```

Comment: getting error pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate... though i have converted the datatype

Comment: Probably you've used bad order of arguments (In the example I've provided there are named arguments used).

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

If you want to use positional arguments, just reorder them that the values are first.

Is this the case?

Comment: ah... sorry my take i posted wrong error message actual error I am getting in the 2nd line where you mentioned how to flatten the df. The error is ValueError: too many value to unpack. In my original df i have 35 rows in Field A and 5 value column